# Meteor: Variable in Variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to update an array with the help of a variable, thats my sourcecode:

```
var y = Flags.findOne({_id: "flagsone"});

// This one works, but I need the other one
// Books.update({_id:book}, {$set: {"score20130901.5": 222}});

   Books.update({_id:book}, {$set: {"score20130901.[y.flag1]": 222}});
```

Have somebody an idea, how I can variables put together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var y = Flags.findOne({_id: "flagsone"});
var props = {};
props["score20130901." + y.flag1] = 222;
Books.update({_id:book}, {$set: props});
```